# Svelte props are not passed to slot

Tags: components, parameter-passing, svelte

I have a component with a slot that I want to pass props to. However, while I *can* pass a variable from the parent directly to the slot, passing it directly from the component that has the slot does not work for some reason. Here is the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/602949b6a7ef42bb88ba5106a9195478?version=3.58.0).

And the code:

```html
<!-- App.svelte -->
<script>
    import Action from "./Action.svelte"
    import Icon from "./Icon.svelte"
    let size = 50;
</script>

<Action id="Home" isActive={true}>
  <Icon {size}/> <!-- works -->
</Action>
```

```html
<!-- Action.svelte -->
<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from "svelte";
    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

    export let isActive = false;
    export let id = "unassigned";
    let size = 12;
    let strokeColor = "#f00";
    let fillColor= "#0f0";
    let fontColor = "#333";

    const enter = () => {
        if (isActive) {
            strokeColor = "#ccc";
            fillColor = "#999";
        }
    };

    const leave = () => {
        strokeColor = "#00f";
        fillColor = "#16e";
    };
</script>

<div on:mouseenter={enter} on:mouseleave={leave}>
    <slot strokeColor={strokeColor} fillColor={fillColor} test={id}/> <!-- does NOT work -->
    <div>action: {size}-{id}-{strokeColor}-{fillColor}</div>
</div>
```

```html
<!-- Icon.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
  export let size = 24;
  export let strokeColor = "#00f";
  export let fillColor = "#0f0";
  export let test = "def";

</script>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" height={size} width={size}
  ><path
    d="M12 3L2 12h3v8h6v-6h2v6h6v-8h3L12 3zm6 15h-2v-6H9v6H7v-7.81l5-4.5 5 4.5V18z"
    fill={strokeColor} /><path
    d="M7 10.19V18h2v-6h6v6h2v-7.81l-5-4.5y"
    fill={fillColor} /></svg>
<div>
icon: {size}, {strokeColor}, {fillColor}, {test}    
</div>
```

`{size}` is correctly passed to the slot, while all the others from `Action.svelte` are ignored:

`<slot strokeColor={strokeColor} fillColor={fillColor} test={id}/>`

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how slot properties work; slots can contain anything and the values are not just automatically passed to any and all contents.

You have to declare the slot properties manually using `let:...` and pass them:

```html
<Action id="Home" isActive={true}
        let:strokeColor let:fillColor let:test>
  <Icon {size} {strokeColor} {fillColor} {test} />
</Action>
```

[Docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-slot-slot-key-value)

Comment: This works, thank you! Just for my understanding: You declare the props with `let:...` so that the compiler knows how to properly pass the variables around, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, see the docs. It can also be used to rename a slot property if in the current scope another name would be better, e.g. to avoid name conflicts.